# Piping data to a fifo with EOFs every second

Tags: echo, read, fifo

I'm trying to pipe some raw binary data through to a fifo (out.pipe), and ensure that EOFs get sent at regular intervals. I do not understand why the following line will not do what I want:

```
while true; do read -t 1 -N 128 line; echo -n $line > out.pipe; done
```

It appears as if, when the timeout occurs, `$line` is given an empty value, and even when it does not occur, all newlines are stripped from the input. This is not my understanding of what should happen according to [this document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

> -N nchars
>
> read returns after reading exactly nchars characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input, unless EOF is encountered or read times out. Delimiter characters encountered in the input are not treated specially and do not cause read to return until nchars characters are read.
>
> -t timeout
>
> Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input (or a specified number of characters) is not read within timeout seconds. timeout may be a decimal number with a fractional portion following the decimal point. This option is only effective if read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when reading from regular files. If read times out, read saves any partial input read into the specified variable name. If timeout is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read and data. The exit status is 0 if input is available on the specified file descriptor, non-zero otherwise. The exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.

Without the `-N 128` parameter on the `read`, and the `-n` parameter on the `echo`, this is very close to what I want. The problem is that newlines are treated special and are sent even when there is no data coming through:

```
while true; do read -t 1 line; echo $line > out.pipe; done
```

I've been testing what goes into my pipe with the following line:

```
while true; do cat out.pipe; done
```

I've tested sending input through stdin as well as sending HTTP data through with `echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: hostname\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80 | myreadcommand`, which was very confusing due to lonely `\r` characters.

What am I failing to understand? Is there a much better way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: i ended up using a python script to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`read`'s man page also says:

> The terminating `<newline>` (if any) shall be removed from the input  and
>          the  results shall be split into fields as in the shell for the results
>          of parameter expansion

It also documents a lot of exceptions based on which parameters you pass to it on how to handle new lines.  Reading the whole man page is necessary if such exceptions matter to you.

If you want to ignore certain characters such as `\r`, that can easily be done with `sed`:

```
echo "hi\r\nI am a script" | sed "s/\r//g"
```

To make the substitution more obvious, you can replace it with something else like:

```
echo "hi\r\nI am a script" | sed "s/\r/,/g"
```

It's also important to note that using the `-e` parameter for `echo` makes it interpret the backslashed special character combinations which do not actually correspond to a real line feed character present in the input.

Comment: I have read the entire page. Is a newline not just the default delimiter? Wouldn't that make the description of `-N` more specific and thus overrule the text you quoted? How should I be piping data with regular EOFs? I want my data to come through unmodified.

Comment: It actually does keep the line feeds when you use `-N`, but not the `\\`.

Comment: I'm confused :/ I am not sending any backslashes to `read`. Maybe that's what I should be doing?

Comment: The complexity of the task lies in the different levels of the shell's interpretation of what you're doing.

Comment: This is what I'm interested in knowing. Could you expound on them please in your answer? I understand the `read` builtin is often used for parsing arguments into variables but my understanding from the description is that if only one name is supplied it all goes into one variable. If `read` is totally the wrong tool for the job I would love an alternate suggestion

Comment: Because of the way named pipes work, I don't understand why you don't simply use `cat` which doesn't parse the input.

Comment: `cat` doesn't have a timeout parameter, how would I tell it to send an EOF?

Comment: If you're building a server that processes the input received, it only needs to act when there is something to process, so it doesn't matter if it waits indefinitely when there's no input.  If you want to do something in parallel to send EOF in parallel, you can do it but that seem rather useless.

Comment: I'd rather have my question answer as asked than my use case doubted. I have another system reading from the fifo, and it requires an EOF to know when to release the fifo. This system has a requirement that it not hang indefinitely. I could maybe implement a timeout on that side but I would like to understand why this way won't work.

Comment: You can always use the `timeout` command to impose a timeout on `cat` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that command! That is very close except any input that takes longer than the timeout is dropped.

Comment: @Nacht:  When dealing with real time systems, you always need to impose a timeout and expect things to go bad from time to time and define ways to recover from them.  Note that piping 1MB of data to a pipe should be instantaneous so I doubt you have a good reason to worry here.